# How to show single page in landscape mode

Tags: jquery, view, ibm-mobilefirst, landscape

We are developing a hybrid mobile application using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 and Jquery 1.4.5.

In this application, we are **showing pages in both landscape and portrait mode**. However, **on one page we don't want to show portrait mode** and want to show **landscape mode** only.

Please explain how to make **one page in entire application show in landscape mode** only.

```js
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#landscapePage",function(){
  
  }
```

above code when i am **navigating** that **landscapePage** in that time i want to **show only landscape only**

Comment: you mean jquey mobile 1.4.5 right

Comment: yes we using jquery mobile and worklight 7.1

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use a plugin using cordova and achive this i have attached the article [Locking jQuery Mobile App Orientation Using Cordova](http://www.gajotres.net/locking-jquery-mobile-app-orientation-using-cordova/).

You have to use the above plugin in your worklight applicaiton and use the `screen.lockOrientation('landscape');` to lock screen orientation.

Hope you know how to add external cordova plugin to your application.
Else follow this link [Android – Adding native functionality to hybrid application with an Apache Cordova plugin](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/)

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id');
    if(activePage === 'index') {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, above code is not working if you have sample project pls post any link

Comment: screen.lockOrientation is not a function error is comming